# Action bar content moves down

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In android versions >5.0 action bar content moves down like on [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btwwJ.jpg). But on android 4.4 and 4.2 all is normal. What should I do to fix it?

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:transitionName="actionBar"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_feed" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_autorenew_black_24dp" />
```

Comment: Try removing padding and elevation from toolbar .

Comment: @ADM it worked, thank you very much!